# Visual Studio Publish Profile for IIS enable windows authentication and disable anonymous

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with a ASPNetCore and React. The template that Visual Studio gives you. ASPNetCore handles the API Code and uses Windows Roles for authentication. I set anonymous auth false and windows auth true in launch.settings. But I do not know if the publish profile has any such setting.

I had to change the publish profile to contain an Environment so it doesn't load npm start on the IIS server execution.

I tried adding a web.config file to the solution but it conflicts with the IIS express settings and it doesn't load. I have set it in IIS directly and it works fine. I can add it directly to the web.config generated by the folder publish but I was hoping there was a way in the publish profile so I didn't have to do it everytime.

Comment: “I didn't have to do it everytime” then why not go to IIS site and configure it there once and for all?

Comment: Because the test server that is not controlled by me may be destroyed and recreated on a whim.  In development I only had to set it once and it persists between publishes but in the test server for some reason this is not happening.

Comment: Your explanation makes little sense. If this server is always recreated to host your site with basic settings like site bindings, I wonder why authentication cannot be made part of that. Keep in mind, authentication is even by default forbidden to be overridden in `web.config` on certain Windows releases.